# Не могу отловить исполнение события onclick через uiwebview или wkwebview

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode

Пытаюсь отловить исполнение события onclick через uiwebview или wkwebview, никаких результатов. Цель: отловить url, который прописан в js функции при клике на div.
Читал всё, что связано с detect js onclick in wkwebview, но не помогло

UPDATE:

```
    func setupWebView() {
    let contentController = WKUserContentController()
    let userScript = WKUserScript(
        source: "getAudio()",
        injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd,
        forMainFrameOnly: true
    )

    contentController.addUserScript(userScript)
    contentController.add(
        self,
        name: "audioHandler"
    )

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = contentController

    wkWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: webViewMain.frame.width, height: webViewMain.frame.height), configuration: config)
    wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self
    webViewMain.addSubview(wkWebView)
}
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print("MESSAGE", message.name)

    if(message.name == "audioHandler") {
        print("JavaScript is sending a message \(message.body)")
    }
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("COMMIT")
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("FINISH")
    self.backItem.isEnabled = webView.canGoBack
    self.forwardItem.isEnabled = webView.canGoForward

    if let webViewRequest = webView.url {
        self.searchBar.searchField.text = webViewRequest.absoluteString
    }

    let js = "getAudioPlayer();"
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("function onclick() { window.webkit.messageHandlers.audioHandler.postMessage(\"HELLO!\"); }") { (data, error) in
        print("ERROR", error, data)
    }
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    switch navigationAction.navigationType {
    case .linkActivated:
        guard let urlRequest = navigationAction.request.url else { return }
        let urlString = urlRequest.absoluteString
        print("URL STRING", urlString)

        for mediaType in AppSettings.mediaTypes {
            if urlString.contains(mediaType) {
                self.getMediaInfo(urlRequest)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            }
        }
    default: break
    }

    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {


    print("URL STRING COMMON", request.url, webView)
    if navigationType == .linkClicked {

    } else if navigationType == .other {
        print("OTHER")
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Покажите сам код.

Comment: @VladGavriuk , я добавил код.